# Is there any Generic printing SDK available for printing from an android app via wifi?

Tags: android, printing, wifi

I am working on an android app which require printing via wifi to a laser printer. Is there any generic code or SDK available which can print through any printer irrespective of printer brand?

Comment: I have not done it myself but did you looked into it- https://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard Android printing APIs, but the user must have a print service installed.

For example the [Mopria Print Service](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mopria.printplugin&hl=en) or the [Samsung Print Service Plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.app.samsungprintservice&hl=en) both print to most WiFi printers available. And for phones with Android O, the [Default Print Service](https://wccftech.com/android-8-0-oreo-default-print-service/) does the same.